# Return the correct Distinguished Name if given a Domain

Tags: javascript, arrays, active-directory

If given an array of domains I need to check and choose the right DN based on the DC

Example: given domain is “red.blue.net”

Check if it exist in a list of Dn’s

const dnArray = ["CN=Larry ,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=COM", "CN=JIM,OU=test,DC=GRE,DC=TEN,DC=COM", "CN=Will,OU=testUsers,DC= Example,DC=COM", "CN=Sam,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=Blue,DC=NET"];

return

"CN=Sam,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=Blue,DC=NET"

```
const dnArray = ["CN=Larry,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=COM", "CN=JIM,OU=test,DC=GRE,DC=TEN,DC=COM", "CN=Will,OU=testUsers,DC= Example,DC=COM"];

const domain = “red.blue.net”

let res = dnArray.map(item => item.split(",")

    .filter(e => e.startsWith("DC="))

    .join(".")

);

for (const dn of dnArray) {

   //if the DCs in domain matches the one for dnArray I want to return right dn "CN=Sam,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=Blue,DC=NET"

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return

> CN=Larry,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=BLUE,DC=COM

```js
    const dnArray = 
        [
          "CN=JIM,OU=test,DC=GRE,DC=TEN,DC=COM",
          "CN=Will,OU=testUsers,DC=Example,DC=COM",
          "CN=Larry,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=COM", 
          "CN=Larry,OU=test,DC=BLUE,DC=COM",
          "CN=Larry,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=BLUE,DC=NET",
          "CN=Larry,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=BLUE,DC=COM"
         ];

    
    var dn;
    const domain = "RED.BLUE.COM" // Will also work as red.blue.net/gov/etc
    
    var dc = domain.toLowerCase().split('.'); // "['red', 'blue', 'com']"

    var included = false;
    
    dnArray.forEach(name => {
        dc.forEach(domain => {
            if(name.toLowerCase().includes('dc=' + domain))
                included = true;        
            else
                included = false;
        });
    
        // If included is true, set dn to equal the current name
        dn =  included ? name : dn; 
    });
    
    console.log(dn);
```

Comment: @jesjolly, I have made some changes to my original answer, let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you for that, Its on the right track but DC can also end with things other then COM such as NET or gov "CN=Larry,OU=test,DC=RED,DC=BLUE,DC=net". It does not need to be case sensitive so you can use toLowecase()

Comment: Removing the line `dc.pop()` will allow it to match using the top-level domain (COM, NET, GOV, etc). And you can add toLowercase() where it is needed. I have updated the snippet one last time with the aforementioned changes.